Не компилируется проект C++ CLI\.NET WInForms. "Здесь нельзя использовать тип управляемый nullptr"
Ошибки находятся в файле "exception" без расширения. Сохранить измененный файл не могу, т.к. пишет, что нет доступа.
Например, ошибка в коде из-за nullptr_t:
#if !_HAS_CXX20
_NODISCARD_FRIEND bool operator==(nullptr_t, const exception_ptr& _Rhs) noexcept {
    return !_Rhs;
}

Или:
_NODISCARD_FRIEND bool operator!=(nullptr_t _Lhs, const exception_ptr& _Rhs) noexcept {
    return !(_Lhs == _Rhs);
}



Устало... На C++/CLI полноценные приложения не пишут. Хотите использовать WinForms - переходите на C#. Хотите освоить нормальный C++ - не касайтесь WinForms и C++/CLI (и на время откажитесь от Visual Studio - это прекрасная IDE, но она вредна для начинающих осваивать C++ именно тем, что подсовывает C++/CLI).

Есть похожий баг-репорт, но там про нативное приложение всё же.

Дело в том, что у меня заказали написать курсовую работу на c++ winforms :/

Передайте лично от меня преподу, который заставляет учить C++/CLI, что он [вырезано цензурой].

Кстати, ошибка появляется когда я подключаю другие файлы строкой: #include <имя файла>
